# How to display all net share users?

Tags: windows, command-line, sharing

With net share command , I can see all the shares but how to display all the users with whom it is shared?

```
C:\Users\erx9adm>net share
Share name   Resource                        Remark
----------------------------------------------------
ADMIN$       C:\Windows                      Remote
F$           F:\                             Default
E$           E:\                             Default
IPC$                                         Remote
C$           C:\                             Default
Arthur       F:\ftp\opentext\SAS\ops_analytics\integ

ASM_CustomerAccessibleData
             F:\interfaces
Billing      F:\ftp\opentext\Billing
BillingInvoiceReport
             F:\ftp\opentext\BillingInvoiceReport

BillPrint_AFP_correspondence
             F:\ftp\opentext\BillPrint_AFP_correspon

BillPrint_IR_letters
             F:\ftp\opentext\BillPrint_IR_letters

BPview_load  F:\ftp\opentext\BPview_load
BW           F:\ftp\opentext\BW
CBCI_File    F:\ftp\opentext\tmp\CBCI_File
```

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell's `Get-SmbShareAccess` cmdlet obtains the share access control list for a given share. That can be combined with `Get-SmbShare` (the PowerShell equivalent of `net share`) to get the ACL for every share:

```
Get-SmbShare | select -pv s | % { Get-SmbShareAccess $s.Name | select Name, @{n='Description'; e={$s.Description}}, @{n='Path'; e={$s.Path}}, AccountName, AccessControlType, AccessRight } | Format-Table
```

Output on my machine:

```
Name         Description     Path                              AccountName               AccessControlType AccessRight
----         -----------     ----                              -----------               ----------------- -----------
ADMIN$       Remote Admin    C:\WINDOWS                        BUILTIN\Administrators                Allow        Full
ADMIN$       Remote Admin    C:\WINDOWS                        BUILTIN\Backup Operators              Allow        Full
ADMIN$       Remote Admin    C:\WINDOWS                        NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE              Allow        Full
C$           Default share   C:\                               BUILTIN\Administrators                Allow        Full
C$           Default share   C:\                               BUILTIN\Backup Operators              Allow        Full
C$           Default share   C:\                               NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE              Allow        Full
FileHistory1                 D:\FileHistory                    *S-1-5-21-[redacted]-1003             Allow        Full
IPC$         Remote IPC                                        BUILTIN\Administrators                Allow        Full
IPC$         Remote IPC                                        BUILTIN\Backup Operators              Allow        Full
IPC$         Remote IPC                                        NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE              Allow        Full
print$       Printer Drivers C:\WINDOWS\system32\spool\drivers Everyone                              Allow        Read
print$       Printer Drivers C:\WINDOWS\system32\spool\drivers BUILTIN\Administrators                Allow        Full
share                        C:\share                          Everyone                              Allow        Full
```

Shares can be listed multiple times, one per security principal granted or denied access.